# HIVE_UNKNOWN_ERROR when running AWS Athena query on Glue table (RDS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, aws-glue

I'm getting an error when running an Athena query against a Glue table created from an RDS database:

> HIVE_UNKNOWN_ERROR: Unable to create input format

The tables are created using a crawler. The tables show up correctly in the Glue interface:

[image: Glue interface]

However, they do not show up in the Athena interface under the database. It says: "The selected database has no tables"

[image]

I do not see this behaviour when using a database created using an S3 file. Maybe this is related to the error. Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same problem. This is the answer that I have got from AWS Support:

> I understand that you set up a Glue crawler to crawl our RDS postresql database but the tables are not visible in Athena.
>
> Athena service is designed to query tables that point to S3 as data-source. It cannot read data from non-S3 resources as of today.

So, unfortunately not possible at the moment.

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Comment: I spent an hour getting my RDS tables populated in Glue - only to find out they cannot be queried via Athena. Nice!!

Comment: Not as long here because I found this question lol.

Comment: But can blue transform data rds to a csv file,  which you can then query form Athena?